# Error while connecting to CVS repository in Windows

Tags: windows, eclipse, cvs

I created repository in my machine №1 (192.168.1.100) and shared project:

[image]

Now, when I trying to connect to repository on machine №1 (192.168.1.100) from my machine №2 (192.168.1.101), I catch an error:

[image]

Connection properties are the same on both machines.

What can be the reason? Thanks for any advice!

**UPD:** When I write in Location properties different address, it immediately says me that *Cannot locate host*. But when i write '192.168.1.100' (my actual address of machine №1), it thinks near 20 seconds and says that it cannot connect. So Eclipse finds it but for some reason cannot connect.

Comment: CVS is quite outdated, for new projects I suggest to use a modern VCS like [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some firewall on 192.168.1.100 drops your CVS packets. To use CVS with the pserver protocol,  traffic on port 2401/tcp must be pass trough.